# Getting a bitmap of the screen when a full screen application is running

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have this code

```
// get the device context of the screen
HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(NULL);
// and a device context to put it in
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, width, height);

// get a new bitmap
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, width, height, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

// clean up
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
```

that generates an `HBITMAP` of the screen. It works perfectly most of the time, but if I try to run it when I have something on full screen on my browser (Youtube, for example), the image captured is not of the video, rather other program running on the background (Visual Studio for me). I suspect the problem is on getting the device context, but I've tried a few alternatives and had the same problems. How can I solve this?

Comment: Videos aren't rendered in a DC, they bypass it. Not sure there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: @MarkRansom so a program like OBS uses another method for capturing the screen? Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: @KleberPF, If nothing else, OBS is open-source, so the answer is available in there somewhere.

Comment: @chris I'm aware, digging through the source right now trying to find it.

Comment: If you can limit to newer Windows versions, try Desktop Duplication API.

Comment: Refer to: [OBS Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Use DirectX method from this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen
After calling GetFrontBufferData you can simply save your bitmap to disk or dig out actual image data and use SetDIBits to assign it to HBITMAP.